# OutOfMemoryError exception when try to blur images

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-bitmap

I'm trying blur some images 1024x1024 and sometimes I'm getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError and i don't know why.

I'm testing directly in my tablet Android 4.1.2 and I have always 1.5gb Ram free.

Here the class I'm using:

```
package com.example.playerclient.blur;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v8.renderscript.*;

public class BlurBuilder {

    private static final float BITMAP_SCALE = 0.6f;


    public static Bitmap blur(Context context, Bitmap image, float blurRadius) {
        Bitmap outputBitmap = null;

        if (image != null) {

            if (blurRadius == 0) {
                return image;
            }

            if (blurRadius < 1) {
                blurRadius = 1;
            }

            if (blurRadius > 25) {
                blurRadius = 25;
            }

            int width = Math.round(image.getWidth() * BITMAP_SCALE);
            int height = Math.round(image.getHeight() * BITMAP_SCALE);

            Bitmap inputBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, false);
            outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(inputBitmap);

            RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(context);
            ScriptIntrinsicBlur theIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
            Allocation tmpIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, inputBitmap);
            Allocation tmpOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, outputBitmap);
            theIntrinsic.setRadius(blurRadius);
            theIntrinsic.setInput(tmpIn);
            theIntrinsic.forEach(tmpOut);
            tmpOut.copyTo(outputBitmap);
        }

        return outputBitmap;
    }
}
```

Here where I call the method:

```
public class MusicaActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    // Others methods here.
    private void mostraDadosMusica() {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Musica musica = (Musica)intent.getSerializableExtra(MainActivity.VISUALIZA_PLAYER);

        // Where i'm having problems.
        Bitmap originalBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), musica.getAlbum().getIdCapa());
        Bitmap resultBmp   = BlurBuilder.blur(this, originalBmp, 15f);
        backgroundImageView.setImageBitmap(resultBmp);
    }
}
```

Ande here the exception message:

> 11-04 22:05:07.453 18928-18928/com.example.playerclient E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
>      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
>      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:636)
>      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:484)
>      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:512)
>      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:542)
>      at com.example.playerclient.activity.MusicaActivity.mostraDadosMusica(MusicaActivity.java:48)
>      at com.example.playerclient.activity.MusicaActivity.onCreate(MusicaActivity.java:87)
>      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5188)
>      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
>      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
>      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
>      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
>      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
>      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
>      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
>      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
>      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: What solutions have You tried? Because OOM when loading/processing image is not a new nor rare issue.

Comment: None. I don't know how to fix this. I'm using 1024x1024 .png images. I'll try convert these images to .jpg and try again but I don't know...

Comment: PNG vs JPG doesn't matter-  when you read them in, you're using uncompressed versions for display.

Comment: THe problem may not even be here-  an OOM error can be caused by any memory leak in your app, or your app just legit using too much memory.  You need to do heap profiling and see where your memory is being used.